# LVN_ITEMCHANGED optimization in ListView control

Tags: c++, windows, listview, winapi, mfc

I'm currently using the following code to update controls in my dialog depending on the rows selected in the list-view control:

```
void CMyDialog::OnLvnItemchangedListTasks(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMLISTVIEW pNMLV = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLISTVIEW>(pNMHDR);
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here

    ASSERT(pNMLV);
    if(pNMLV->uChanged & LVIF_STATE)
    {
        if((pNMLV->uNewState ^ pNMLV->uOldState) & LVIS_SELECTED)
        {
            //List selection changed
            updateDlgControls();
        }
    }

    *pResult = 0;
}
```

This method works, except that it's **REALLY slow**!

For instance, if my list has about 100 items in it and then I click on the first item and Shift-click on the last item (to select all items) it locks up my app for about several seconds. This won't happen if I comment out my `updateDlgControls` in the example above.

Is there a way to optimize the processing of LVN_ITEMCHANGED?

For instance, for 100 selected items, it's called for each and every one of them.

**EDIT:** Following [Jonathan Potter's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25796819/843732) I changed it to this, which seems to do the job quite nicely:

```
void CMyDialog::OnLvnItemchangedListTasks(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMLISTVIEW pNMLV = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLISTVIEW>(pNMHDR);
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here

    ASSERT(pNMLV);
    if(pNMLV->uChanged & LVIF_STATE)
    {
        if((pNMLV->uNewState ^ pNMLV->uOldState) & LVIS_SELECTED)
        {
            //Use the timer to optimize processing of multiple notifications
            //'LVN_CHANGE_OPTIMIZ_TIMER_ID' = non-zero timer ID
            //If SetTimer is called when timer was already set, it will be reset without firing it
            ::SetTimer(this->GetSafeHwnd(), LVN_CHANGE_OPTIMIZ_TIMER_ID, 1, OnLvnItemchangedListTasksTimerProc);
        }
    }

    *pResult = 0;
}

static VOID CMyDialog::OnLvnItemchangedListTasksTimerProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT_PTR idEvent, DWORD dwTime)
{
    VERIFY(::KillTimer(hwnd, idEvent));

    ASSERT(hwnd);
    ::PostMessage(hwnd, WM_APP_PROCESS_LVN_ITEMCHANGED, 0, 0);
}

ON_MESSAGE(WM_APP_PROCESS_LVN_ITEMCHANGED, OnDelayed_updateDlgControls)

LRESULT CMyDialog::OnDelayed_updateDlgControls(WPARAM, LPARAM)
{
    //List selection changed
    updateDlgControls();

#ifdef _DEBUG
    static int __n = 0;
    TRACE(CStringA(EasyFormat(L"Updated list count=%d\n", __n++)));
#endif
}
```

There's only one caveat that I see in this approach. One needs to make sure to check for disabled conditions additionally in processing methods for UI controls that can be disabled by the `updateDlgControls()` method, since having introduced a delay we can run into a problem when the processing method for a UI control can be called before the timer procedure had a chance to call `updateDlgControls()` method that normally disables UI controls. (This may happen, for instance, if a user repeatedly clicks shortcut keys on the keyboard.) By doing secondary checks in processing methods we make sure that disabled methods don't cause a crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this using a flag and a timer. When you get a state change message, set a flag that indicates the state has changed, and use `SetTimer` to kick off a short (even 1ms would probably do) timer. Since timers are low priority it won't fire while other messages, like `WM_NOTIFY` are in your queue. When the timer expires, kill it and then update your UI state.

(The flag is simply used so that you don't recreate the timer over and over again - once the timer has fired, use `KillTimer` to kill it and clear the flag ready for next time).

Comment: You don't need a flag.  The fact that you have a running timer is enough, since you have the timer ID.  If the timer is already allocated, you can skip re-creating it.

Comment: I would probably have the timer running constantly instead of a one-off. Set a flag when an item changes, then have the timer periodically check the flag. If set, reset it and update the controls according to the current state. An alternative would be to have the message loop itself check the flag.  Whenever a new message is processed and then there are no more messages available, check the flag and act accordingly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: How do you know the timer is already allocated? There's no DoesTimerExist api.

Comment: Your second comment would introduce lag in the refresh of the UI depending on the period of your timer. Plus it seems a little inefficient to constantly run a timer and check a flag that's only need in response to specific user input.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: I love the timer solution. I just tried it and it works great. Speeds it up x1000 times, maybe even more. I posted an update in my original question.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: `SetTimer()` gives you a timer ID. Simply don't call `SetTimer()` again if you have already been given an ID.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: If you start using timer ID then you'll need to store it somewhere to reset it later. It doesn't seem to have much of a "performance hit" if I simply call `SetTimer` directly. It will not set the timer repeatedly if it was already set.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: It does if you use a thread timer, not if it's a window timer. But you already know this :)

Comment: @JonathanPotter: `SetTimer()` returns a non-zero value, whether you associate it with an `HWND` or not. If you use an `HWND`, you pass your own ID number to `SetTimer()` and `KillTimer()`. Otherwise, `SetTimer()` returns an ID that you have to pass to `KillTimer()`. Either way, a non-zero value returned from `SetTimer()` is your indication that `SetTimer()` has already been called.  But whatever. This line of comments has dragged on too long. Your solution has been implemented by the OP, so he needs to mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I fully agreee, I'm just curious what you think the semantic difference is between a flag and a known constant value stored in a variable. But anyway, yes gone on too long :)

Answer (score 3):

You should consider using the ListView in virtual mode instead (enabling the `LVS_OWNERDATA` style).  It has vast improved performance over a non-virtual ListView, since you dont store the list item data in the ListView itself, it just displays data you provide from another source of your choosing.  As such, it offers some additional notifications for optimizing item retrievals and updates.  The `LVN_ITEMCHANGED` [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774845.aspx) states:

> If a list-view control has the LVS_OWNERDATA style, and the user selects a range of items by holding down the SHIFT key and clicking the mouse, LVN_ITEMCHANGED notification codes are not sent for each selected or deselected item. Instead, you will receive a single LVN_ODSTATECHANGED notification code, indicating that a range of items has changed state.

Comment: It doesn't sound like the OP has a huge dataset, just an expensive UI update function. Owner data would add a lot of overhead that may not be justified. A valid solution however.

Comment: I agree. Changing the whole thing to owner-drawn is a little bit more than what I was looking for. Although it's a nice thing to know. Thanks.

Comment: @c00000fd: I did not say owner-draw.  I said owner-data.  Two different things.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Sorry, I misspoke. It still requires a big overwrite of the app's logic.

Comment: @c00000fd: it may or may not require a re-write, depending on where your data is coming from and how you add it to the ListView. For example, if you have a fixed array, you can simply put a state field in the array, and use the ListView notifications to keep that state updated. When the ListView needs data, it asks you for it. When you need to access data, you just go to the array directly.

Comment: Selecting 100 items is fast with either owner data or list owned data. The real issue is working where all the time is spent. Far from clear yet.