# LVM_GETNEXTITEM can't find item in listview

Tags: c++, listview, winapi

I have a serious problem with listview in c++. 
I create one like this:

```
RECT rcl;
GetClientRect( hWnd, & rcl );
lvC = CreateWindowEx( 0, WC_LISTVIEW, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LVS_REPORT |
LVS_EDITLABELS, 0, 0, rcl.right - rcl.left, 200 - rcl.top,
hWnd,( HMENU ) 1000, hInstance, NULL );

ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(lvChannels, LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);

LVCOLUMN lvc;
lvc.mask = LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM;
lvc.iSubItem = 0;
lvc.cx = 750;
lvc.pszText = (char*)"Name";
ListView_InsertColumn( lvC, 0, & lvc );
```

And insert items this way:
    int row = 0;

```
for (const auto& c : cVec)
{
    LVITEM lvi;
    lvi.mask = LVIF_TEXT;

    lvi.pszText = (LPSTR)c.name.c_str();
    lvi.iItem = row;
    lvi.iSubItem = 0;

    ListView_InsertItem( lvC, & lvi );
    row++;
}
```

After that I want to handle when user select a row in this listview. I've tried something like this:

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
    {
        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
            case 1000:
                if(((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == NM_CLICK) 
                {
                    auto iSelect=SendMessage(lvC, LVM_GETNEXTITEM, -1, LVNI_SELECTED);

                    if(iSelect==-1)
                    {
                        MessageBox(hWnd,"No Items in ListView",
                        "Error",MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        std::string t = "Selected item: " + std::to_string(iSelect);
                        MessageBox(hWnd, t.c_str(),
                        "Error",MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately when I click on this listview I get "No Items in ListView" and I can't select any. I would like to emphasize that there are correct items in listview and I can scroll it but when I click on It, It doesn't mark.
Thank you in advance for all your help!

Comment: @RichardCritten Where should I use it?

Comment: @RichardCritten is this a proper solution for ListVIew or just for ListBox?

Comment: `LBN_SELCHANGE` is a listbox control `WM_COMMAND` notification. It's not a listview notification.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thank You. I need a solution for listView.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `NM_CLICK` is sent before the listview processes the click. At the time you get the notification the item isn't actually selected yet.

The correct notification to look for is `LVN_ITEMCHANGED`, which is sent whenever the state of an item changes, including its selection state.

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
    if (reinterpret_cast<LPNMHDR>(lParam)->code == LVN_ITEMCHANGED)
    {
        auto plv = reinterpret_cast<NMLISTVIEW*>(lParam);
        if ((plv->uNewState & LVIS_SELECTED) != (plv->uOldState & LVIS_SELECTED))
        {
            // selection state of an item has changed
        }
    }
    break;
```

Comment: You don't need to compare old and new state. Just `if(plv->uChanged & LVIS_SELECTED)` is sufficient.

Comment: @zett42 Do You have any idea why I can't select row?

Comment: @BartoszMajkut What do you mean by "I can't select row"?

Comment: @zett42 I used code from Jonathan and when I click on listview I can't mark anything.

Comment: @BartoszMajkut Clearly, what you are observing can't stem from Jonathans code. This code is just observing, it doesn't change the way selection works in the list view control. I believe this problem stems from the part of your code we don't see. To narrow the problem down, remove pieces of code until the problem no longer happens. Then add back code until it happens again. You may now get an idea what causes the problem.

Comment: @zett42 Something started to work, but when I add Your code 
    `if(plv->uChanged & LVIS_SELECTED)`
It doesn't recognize changing selection.

Comment: @BartoszMajkut I made a mistake. It should be `if(plv->uChanged & LVIF_STATE){ if ((plv->uNewState & LVIS_SELECTED) != (plv->uOldState & LVIS_SELECTED)){ /* selection state of an item has changed */ } }`. Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25796586/7571258).